# xsl: Check if node exists, concatenate and trim

Tags: xslt

I have a newbie question.
In my XML I have 3 elements:

```
...
    <Person>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Surname>Doe</Surname>
        <AlternativeName>Unknown Person</AlternativeName>
    </Person>
...
```

**The business rules are very simple:**

1. Concatenate Name and Surname i.e. concat(./Person/Name, ' ', ./Person/Surname)
2. If result from point 1 is blank then use ./Person/AlternativeName
3. There must be no leading or trailing spaces in the final result

How do I implement the above rules, considering the following:

1. Name and/or Surname could be empty e.g. `<Name></Name>`
2. Name and/or Surname might not be present in the XML e.g.

```
...
    <Person>
        <AlternativeName>Unknown Person</AlternativeName>
    </Person>
...
```

If this was Java or C# or Delphi, I would simply concatenate the fields, trim leading and trailing spaces and test the result...

Comment: The only attempt to use XSLT/XPath seems to be `concat(./Person/Name, ' ', ./Person/Surname)`, I wonder what the context is as you don't show the container of `Person` or whether it can contain several `Person`s but I don't see any attempt to check whether that gives a blank result. Are you not able to find `if (conditional-exp) then exp1 else exp2` in XPath 2 or later or `xsl:choose/xsl:when` or `xsl:if` in your favourite XSLT tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normalize-space() function to remove leading/trailing spaces. It will also reduce other spaces to the one space in case the concatenation leaves you with multiple spaces between values.

For example like this:

```
normalize-space(concat(/Person/Name,' ',/Person/Surname))
```

You can use either xsl:choose or xsl:if  to determine wether or not to use the AlternativeName as Martin mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Thanks Ophychius, that solved half my problem. I do use choose to check if Surname is empty i.e.  <xsl:when test="./Person/Surname = ''">. This only works when the element is present but empty. Ideally I want to also test if the element does not exist. How would I do the following: If (Surname element does not exist) or (Surname element = '') do something.

Comment: The answer seems to answer your question as written. Your comment seems to be asking a supplementary question, which is best avoided: better to raise a new question. However, try `xsl:if test="not(string(Person/Surname))`.